# Upgrade PostgreSQL 9.3 without moving the DB and messing PostGIS on OSX OpenGeo Suite original installation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, upgrade, postgis, mac-os-x

I looked for the answer, but could not find a specifically fitting one, so would appreciate an answer or a pointer to one...

**Q**: How do I upgrade PostgreSQL 9.3  to the current (now 9.6 ?) without having problems with PostGIS (mine is 2.1.7 and I would like to upgrade to the current PostGIS 2.3.2 as well)?

My configuration is as following:

```
select version();
PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn), 64-bit

psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.3

SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
postgis_full_version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGIS="2.1.7 r13414" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
(1 row)

About PostGIS:OpenGeo Suite 4.8 PG-9.3.4 PostGIS-2.1.7

OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011), MacintoshSSD + HD hybrid installation, system on the SSD, 8GB memory
```

I originally installed via Boundless OpenGeo Suite 4.8 (it was free at the time) but cannot find anything about upgrading except this general [page](https://boundlessgeo.com/boundless-suite/). I suppose they went commercial.

**Q2**:Is there a free alternative, preferably without having to redefine and move everything?

**Q3**: Is following the [Upgrading PostGIS](http://postgis.net/install/) instructions going to mess my currently working install?

The idea is to have a free and powerful GIS-PostgreSQL bundle that works fast on big spatial data sets. Preferably something that students could install on their own. As of now we do visualisations of results via QGIS.

Comment: anybody can advise?

Comment: I joined this SE community to upvote and fav. your question as I'm also interested in upgrading. If I get something I'll let you know...